# Can bronze be electroplated with zinc?

Tags: electrochemistry

I had to have a motorcycle part cast in bronze that was originally steel. I want to electroplate it with zinc. Will this work? Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to or want to?

Answer (score 1):

Bronze is mainly copper (with a bit of tin in it) which can be electroplated with Zn and then heated to form Brass (Copper-zinc alloy): https://www.stem.org.uk/resources/elibrary/resource/33571/zinc-plating-copper-and-formation-brass-%E2%80%93turning-copper-%E2%80%98silver%E2%80%99.

Also this question has been discussed extensively here: https://www.finishing.com/126/37.shtml.